# Instaciate a generic type

Tags: java, generics, instance, type-parameter

Consider the following generic class:

```
class MyClass<T>{
    T field;//ok
    public void method (T t){...}//ok
    public <E> MyClass(E[] e){
        E ee= new E();// compile error
        T t= new T();// compile error
    }
}
```

Why we cant instanciate of `T` and `E`? We know all about of types `T,E` at run time. I think that the type parameters `T,E` can be considered as a some reference type.

Comment: `T` and `E` don't exist at runtime.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that should be an answer :P

Comment: Read about `type erasure` in Generics.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis After type erasure at compile time we have that `E,T` are defined to `Object`. What problems to instanciate of `Object`? I dont undestand.

Comment: `T` isn't necessarily going to be `Object`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Why not necessarily? `T,E` without bounds, hence after type erasure `T,E` are defined to `Object` at compile time

Comment: That's not how it works. And even if it did, it would immediately fail at runtime. See the linked question in a previous comment.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Does at compile time `new` operator  requires a specific type? Compiler checked this before type erasure, but at the type checked.